# Attribute error __aenter__ Airflow deferrable sensor

Tags: python, airflow, python-asyncio

So, basically I am trying to create a deferrable sensor in airflow by following the guide [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/deferring.html#writing-deferrable-operators).

So, basically, my trigger's async run method has been written like this

```
async def run(self):
    while True:
        with MsSqlIntegratedHook(mssql_conn_id=self.mssql_conn_id).get_cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(self.sql)
            rows = cursor.fetchone()
            if rows[0] > 0:
                yield TriggerEvent(True)
        await asyncio.sleep(self.sleep_interval)
```

It always errors out by saying : `Attribute error: __aenter__  at the line cursor.execute`

I have tried many different versions, one of which is, introducing, async keyword in with cursor i.e.

```
async with MsSqlIntegratedHook(mssql_conn_id=self.mssql_conn_id).get_cursor() as cursor:
```

but then the error remains the same , it just shifts to to the while loop instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/jobs/triggerer_job.py", line 297, in cleanup_finished_triggers
    result = details["task"].result()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/jobs/triggerer_job.py", line 361, in run_trigger
    async for event in trigger.run():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow_plugin/triggers/sql_trigger.py", line 22, in run
    while True:

AttributeError: __aenter__
```

I have also tried introducing these magic methods (**aenter** and **aexit**) in the MsSqlIntegratedHook class (with just pass).

I have tried reading documentation and also some posts, but not sure what is missing.

Can someone explain, why do I see this error, and what should I do?

Comment: seems like you may need a context manager for the async stuff: [https://blog.finxter.com/python-__aenter__-magic-method/](https://blog.finxter.com/python-__aenter__-magic-method/) ? you can search online for `__aenter__` or perhaps the code is thinking something is a context manager which isn't? can't you get some more verbose logging?

Comment: by sheer chance, while making adhoc changes to the installed modules (because I am working inside a docker container), to test what the problem was- I found that one of the problems remained even though I fixed it. That led me to believe it was something to do with pycache, I removed the cache and now the code works. This is bizzare, because I had 2 versions of the module and used pipenv to lock and sync , several times , yesterday and none of them worked.